# How to insert a value in a trigger

Tags: sql, triggers

Im trying to insert a value when the condition occurs but it give me the error ambiguos column name
the code is:

```
create trigger B
on ALUNOS
after update, insert
as 
begin 
update ALUNOS
set média_final = 9 from inserted where média_final < 9
end
```

Comment: Which database management system are you using?

Comment: Are you sure you can use spanish letters (é) in column names?

Comment: 1) What database is it? 2) My guess would be that it chokes on a field containing "é" letter. You should stick to ASCII charset for table/column names.

Answer (score 0):

```
create trigger B
on ALUNOS
after update, insert
as 
begin 
update ALUNOS
set média_final = 9 
from inserted i where i.média_final < 9
end
```

The ambiguous column is média_final  which is in both tables. Specifying which table it came from is what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

try to follow this

update table set column = value where column = value

change value for the value that you want, you can add null or change null, don`t ever forget '' for string and lose it for numbers